# How to register External Service (Non MSA) On Eureka Discovery registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, kibana, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am using Kibna inside Docker.

I am running the Kibana using docker-compose

Below is My docker-compose.yml

```
  version: '2'
    services:
      elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch
        expose:
          - 9200
        ports:
          - "9200:9200"
        networks:
          - cloud      
      
      
      fluentd:
        build: ./fluentd
        volumes:
          - ./fluentd/conf:/fluentd/etc
        links:
          - "elasticsearch"
        ports:
          - "24224:24224"
          - "24224:24224/udp"
        networks:
          - cloud  
      
    
      kibana:
        image: kibana
        links:
          - "elasticsearch"
        ports:
          - "9201:5601"
        networks:
          - cloud
    
    networks:
      cloud:
       driver: bridge
```

I want to enroll this Kibana application on Eureka discovery registry

so that I can call this using API-gateway

Below Is the sample the way I enroll My API-gateway on Eureka

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 60
  instance:
    hostname: api-gateway
    prefer-ip-address: false
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5000
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 5000
```

API-gateway is a spring-boot application so it's straightforward.

I am running kibana using docker (Image). How can I achieve the same for this

Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks In advance

Comment: have you created a sidecar application with `spring-cloud-netflix-sidecar`? Have a look at this example http://stytex.de/blog/2016/01/18/spring-cloud-sidecar-applications/

Comment: @Paizo, that could be an answer if you elaborate it a bit more.

Comment: @Paizo : It seems **Tukaram** is using default docker image for Kibana and he wants to register the same service on Eureka using docker compose

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh: Yes correct

Comment: Hi @TukaramPatilPune! Did you every try the spring-cloud sidecar approach? Did you get it working? And was my answer below any help?

Answer (score 2):

Registering a java application with Eureka is not a big deal, because Netflix supplies a java Eureka client that is included in your classpath when using the `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` dependency. And Spring Boot will configure this client from your application properties.

Registering and application from outside the application code is different situation. You can certainly still do this.

I will just mention a little theory here, and then get to a suggested solution.

## Theory

The basic way to do this, is to use the [Eureka REST operations](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations). This is an API where you can manually register/unregister service instances, and supply a regular heartbeat for Eureka to consider the service instance available.

It's really not a very large API, and with your current knownledge of Eureka client configuration you would probably have an easy time.

## Solution with spring-cloud-netflix-sidecar

Spring Cloud already has your usecase covered! The approach here is that you will create a companion container for kibana, a sidecar. And the application in this container will be responsible for registering your service with Euerka. This type of application is very small, it will be quick to implement with Java and Spring Cloud.

Here's the documentation from Spring Cloud: [Polyglot support with Sidecar](https://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_polyglot_support_with_sidecar)

Here's a tutorial on it: [Spring Cloud Netflix Sidecar Tutorial](http://craftcodecrew.com/spring-cloud-netflix-sidecar-tutorial/)

And here's a repository that does this in a very simple way: [Spring-Cloud-Sidecar_Tutorial](https://github.com/CraftcodeCrew/Spring-Cloud-Sidecar_Tutorial)

There is almost no code in the sidecar application, only this application class (taken from the repository above):

```java
package com.craftcodecrew.lumen.service.sidecar;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.sidecar.EnableSidecar;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSidecar
public class LumenServiceSidecarApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LumenServiceSidecarApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This configuration:

```yaml
server:
  port: 5678

spring:
  application:
    name: lumen-service

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true

sidecar:
  port: ${SIDECAR_PORT:8000}
  health-uri: ${SIDECAR_HEALTH_URI:http://localhost:8000/health}
  home-page-uri: ${SIDECAR_HOMEPAGE_URI:http://localhost:8000/}
```

And a very simple [pom.xml](https://github.com/CraftcodeCrew/Spring-Cloud-Sidecar_Tutorial/blob/master/lumen-service-sidecar/pom.xml).

As you can see, the sidecar library takes some configuration that you need to point to your kibana instance. So, they need to be on the same network. And also on the same network as Eureka.

Provided that your kibana container name is 'kibana', your config would look like this:

```yaml
server:
  port: 5678

spring:
  application:
    name: kibana

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://eureka:8761/eureka}
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true

sidecar:
  port: ${SIDECAR_PORT:5601}
  health-uri: ${SIDECAR_HEALTH_URI:http://kibana:5601/status}
  home-page-uri: ${SIDECAR_HOMEPAGE_URI:http://kibana:5601/}
```

You could also control those values in environment variables configured in the docker-compose definition. Like so:

```yaml
  kibana-sidecar:
    image: kibana-sidecar
    links:
      - "kibana"
    ports:
      - "5678:5678"
    environment:
      - EUREKA_URI=<your_eureka_instance_uri>
      - SIDECAR_PORT=5601
      - SIDECAR_HEALTH_URI=http://kibana:5601/status
      - SIDECAR_HOMEPAGE_URI=http://kibana:5601/
    networks:
      - cloud
```